# java no me solicita escribir y simplemete termina la ejecucion del codigo

Tags: java

lo que sucede es que mi codigo solo se ejecuta hasta la linea de codigo en negrita y no me solicita la entrada de datos para este pero para los demas de arriba si.

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    double altopared;
    double anchopared;
    double altopanel;
    double anchopanel;
    String nombre;

    System.out.println("introduce la altura del panel en pulgadas");
    altopanel=sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("introduce el ancho del panel en pulgadas");
    anchopanel=sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("ahora introduce el alto de la pared en pulgadas");
    altopared=sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("introduce el ancho de la pared en pulgadas");
    anchopared=sc.nextDouble();
    
    **System.out.println("introduce tu nombre");**
    nombre =sc.nextLine();
    if (nombre.equals("samuel")){
        System.out.println("tu nombre es "+nombre);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

El usar un .nextLine() luego de usar un .nextInt() o similares produce este comportamiento esto se debe a que los metodos tales como .nextInt() utilizan el salto de linea (\n) para considerar el final de la entrada. El buffer de entrada mantiene este valor y al usar luego .nextLine() este es el valor que se recupera.

Como solución podrías agregar una primera lectura para que limpie el buffer y consecutivamente una segunda donde si capturarias el valor.

```
sc.nextLine(); // Limpia el buffer
nombre =sc.nextLine(); // Se recupera el valor ingresado.
```

Answer (score 1):

No se porque no espera el próximo enter tu código, pero con

```
nombre = sc.next("\\w+");
```

en ves que `nextLine` consigues que se detenga y espere el texto y próximo enter. `\\w+` es una expresión regular que significa cualquier una cadena de texto de 1 o más caracteres https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html

Comment: pero no entiendo porque cuando elimino todos los system.out.println antes que este, el codigo si se ejecuta bien